# Removing space in a table cell caused by <a> tag

Tags: css

I'm working on an email signature and I want all three rows below to have the smallest possible height. With the third row extra vertical space appears probably because it contains links, as opposed to just span tags. I'd like to remove that additional vertical space.

Is there inline CSS that I can add that's not here already to eliminate that?

I don't want to add more space and make the row height larger.

```
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><span class="appleLinks" style="color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; line-height: 14px;">Address|&nbsp;Address Line 2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><span class="appleLinks" style="color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; line-height: 14px;">tel: &nbsp;|&nbsp;fax: </span></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td height="0" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">  <a style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;"  href="mailto:name@name.com"><span style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" >name@name.com</span></a>&nbsp;
  <a style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/name"><span style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" >LinkedIn</span></a>&nbsp;
  <a style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" href="http://www.website.com"><span style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" >www.website.com</span></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What browser are you trying this in?

I can't seem to duplicate your problem. I tried it in Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94) and Firefox (version 16.0.2):

Here's a JSfiddle: http://tinyurl.com/a9dseu5

You didn't have your full code, so I assumed some things about the table.

I included the border so it's possible to see how much space is between the text and the cell wall.

I don't know of any CSS that can modify any extra pixels in fonts (if that's the problem), but in general margin and padding should be set to 0 as you have done. Once I can duplicated your problem then I'll be able to better figure out the problem.

Comment: Please include your code in your answer, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: This isn’t really an answer. Requests for clarification and notes that a problem cannot be reproduced belong to comments.

Comment: Was working in Widows 7/Chrome and my table structure and attributes was the same as your example. What seems to be working now is to add line-height declaration in the style attribute of the td

Answer (score 1):

It’s not the link, it’s the spaces that cause the problems. In the cell, there are space characters outside elements. The spaces have a font size, probably the default font size of the page, and this increases the height requirements.

The simplest solution is to set `font-size: 10px; font-family: Georgia` in the `style` attribute for the `td` element. You could then remove those settings from elements inside the `td`. Caveat: I’m no expert in HTML e-mail, and I cannot tell whether some e-mail clients fail to support setting such properties on table cells (but I would find it odd).

An alternative solution is to remove all space characters and newlines from the content of the `td` element.

P.S. I find 10px Georgia very unreadable. It’s perhaps not illegal, but it should be.

Comment: Or just surround your td content with a copy of your _span_. `<td height="0" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><span style="color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" >{{content}}</span></td>`

Comment: Confused because that seems similar to what I had in the original example?